# SignalR self host on azure worker role

Tags: signalr, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I will deploy a SignalR application on an Azure Worker role - Cloud Services. To make it work I found [this](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/host-owin-in-an-azure-worker-role). I noticed a `while (true)` with a `Thread.Sleep` of 10 seconds. Do you think this is the best interval to keep the server alive or I can increase it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the sole purpose of that Thread.Sleep(10000) there is to avoid flooding the logs with that Trace statement. If you're happy enough to get a log entry saying "Working" every minute or so, I'd say increase it.